# Do electrons have a size or mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electricity, electrons

Do [electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron) have any size if not then how do they collide with positive fixed in in wires?

Comment: Electrons interact via the Coulomb force but the physical size of an electron is another matter which is described here: https://gravityandlevity.wordpress.com/2015/04/11/how-big-is-an-electron/ The electron could be a "point" but still have a sphere of influence.

Comment: To reopen this post (v2) consider clarifying the last sentence in an edit.

Comment: I meant to say how can a particle with no size collide with any particle. I was thinking intuitively .

Comment: Also note that e.g. the mass of the electron is listed in the right margin of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron). Phys.SE usually requires a minimum of research before asking.

Comment: Ok. I will take care of that from now on. But for now please remove the hold on my question. Qmechanic

Comment: @ObsessionWithElectricity the question in its present state cannot be reopened. It still states a question whose answer is clearly presented in the wikipedia page. Mention some things you read while doing the research for this question, or something which you thought of which confused you.

Comment: Note that you have already been told that questions require significant prior research (and been given a link to a Physics SE meta page about what you're supposed to try before asking); your question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/427416) was closed on similar grounds, except there we happened to find a Physics SE post with an identical title so it ended up as a duplicate. But AFT's comment there clearly mentions that questions are supposed to be preceded by basic research.

Answer (score 4):

electrons have mass, but at the resolution limits of our current technology they appear to have no size i.e., they are like mathematical points.

However, the electric field that is propagated into space in the vicinity of every electron has a range of action extending to infinity (where its strength becomes almost zero) and becoming strong at length scales of order ~one atom diameter.

So when an electron recoils, for example, off another electron, it is not that the pointlike electrons themselves collide and the electrons "bounce" off each other. Instead, it is the repulsive force between the electrostatic fields (which have finite extent) of the two electrons that causes them to bounce off one another- almost as if the electrons themselves were of finite size, and in some sense elastic and rubbery.

Answer (score 2):

Yes electrons have a mass of $9.10938188 × 10^{-31}$ kilograms. They collide because of electromagnetic force and Pauli exclusion. For all we know it has zero radius: no experiment has demonstrated a finite radius.

Answer (score -1):

Mass of electron is 9x10^-31. But it has no size .Because, in the vision of quantum mechanics, electron is considered as 
a point particle with no volume and its size is also unclear.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it has a mass and velocity but mass can be neglected as it very small as nucleus contain proton and neutron.

And the mass of a proton is equal to the mass of a neutron. And the mass of a neutron or proton = 1800 times that of an electron.

So nucleus is bigger than electron by 3600 times (As 2×1800) 
So electron have mass but very small and can be neglected (According to mass of nucleus )

Comment: Please use appropriate punctuation. Avoid excessive usage of '...' I've edited it here but if you write several such answers, they will be deleted.